# Getting an ACK failure right away after writing slave address in interrupt mode for I2C [STM32F4]

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, c, i2c, embedded

I see that once slave address is written in the interrupt handler, I get an ACK Failure right away, but when I do the same thing with polling approach, I do get an ACK and goes on to read off the values from the device.

With interrupts, I see ISR gets triggered only once (in which it writes slave address) and never gets called again. My i2c configurations are fine, but there's something with interrupts that I seem to be missing out on.

**Polling approach**

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit (I2C *hi2c, uint8_t *data, uint8_t size)
{
            GenerateStartCondition();

            // validate the completion of start condition   
            while (!GetFlagStatus(hi2c->Instance, I2C_SR1_SB) && HAL_Timeout(5));

            // write slave address along with write bit
            I2C_WriteSlaveAddress(hi2c, WRITE);

            // wait for address to be sent
            while (!GetFlagStatus(hi2c->Instance, I2C_SR1_ADDR) && HAL_Timeout(5));

            // clear address flag
            I2C_ClearADDRFlag(hi2c->Instance);

            // write data to DR ...
}
```

**With interrupts:**

```
void HAL_StartI2CInterrupts() {
     GenerateStartCondition();

    // setting control bits
    hi2c->Instance->CR2 |= I2C_CR2_ITBUFEN;
    hi2c->Instance->CR2 |= I2C_CR2_ITEVTEN;
    hi2c->Instance->CR2 |= I2C_CR2_ITERREN;

void I2C1_EV_IRQHandler () 
{

    uint8_t event_interrupt = (hi2c->Instance->CR2 & I2C_CR2_ITEVTEN) >> I2C_CR2_ITEVTEN_Pos;

    uint8_t buffer_interrupt = (hi2c->Instance->CR2 & I2C_CR2_ITBUFEN) >> I2C_CR2_ITBUFEN_Pos;

    uint8_t var;

    if (event_interrupt)
    {
        //  validate the completion of START condition
        var =  (hi2c->Instance->SR1 & I2C_SR1_SB) >> I2C_SR1_SB_Pos;
        if (var)
        {
            if (hi2c->I2C_State == I2C_TX_BUSY)
            {               
                I2C_WriteSlaveAddress(hi2c, WRITE);     
            }
        }
         // check ADDR bit ...
     }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's your problem, but as a general rule, avoid doing too much in an interrupt handler. It is a bit suspicious that you are calling I2C_WriteSlaveAddress inside the handler, unless that is how it is intended to be used.

Comment: I need to service the i2c interrupt though. After generating the start condition, I have to send the slave address for me to talk to it, no? @Justin

Comment: Yes, looking at other examples online, it looks like it is fine. Can you look at SDA/SCL on a scope and see if the slave device is actually not sending an ACK?

Comment: Yes, it does not. Do you know if there's any particular way of using interrupts? the only thing I can think of is using incorrect slave address which clearly isn't the case cause it does work with polling method. @Justin

Comment: also, does it make sense to call `HAL_StartI2CInterrupts()` repeatedly till TXing is done/stop-condition is generated? to me it doesn't make sense but I saw an example online that does that. @Justin

Comment: I'm suspicious of the HAL_Timeout(5) call.  That's not a standard HAL function.  What does it do?

Comment: It is a piece of advice rather than directly answer your question. using HAL_I2C_Mem_Read_IT() and HAL_I2C_Mem_Write_IT() handles ACK bits.

Answer (score 1):

ST's HAL could be generating a racing condition when called inside an ISR. As mentioned by @Justin, you don't want to occupy the CPU for too long when in an ISR. For your NACK when writing inside an ISR I see two solutions:

1. Use a flag. Set it on the ISR, on your main loop check for the raised flag, if so send the data through I2C;
2. Use DMA. HAL DMA calls are not blocking and the driver will deal with writing on the peripheral themselves.

Solution **1** is simpler but less deterministic. **1** would look something like:

```
static volatile uint8_t i2cSendFlag = 0;

void I2C1_EV_IRQHandler(void){
    i2cSendFlag = 1;
    I2C_ClearFlag(<the active ISR on your code>);
}

static I2CDoWork(void){
    if(i2cSendFlag){
        // Send your data

        // Clear the send flag
        i2cSendFlag = 0;
    }
}

int main(void){
    I2CConfig(I2C1);
    for(;;){
        I2CDoWork();
        // Rest of your code
    }
}
```

The ISR being called only once seems like peripheral's flags are not been cleared. From [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqhWG.png) each active ISR event is cleared by a differently method. On your HAL configuration step witch event flags are active? Check the below table to see how to clear the corresponding event on the ISR function.

[image: I2C IRQ requests]